# Android get Locale Currency

Tags: android, concurrency, locale

I have ran into a little tricky thing here.
The thing is that I want to get the Locale Currency of the User, so I do this:

```
final Locale currentLocale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
final Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(currentLocale);
mCurrencyCode = currency.getCurrencyCode();
```

Which gives me: **AUD** as for Australia

The problem? Well, I am in New Zealand and the Currency Code is **NZD**

How could I get the right Currency Code?

Cheers

Comment: Is your `currentLocale` initialized with New Zealand? or Australia?

Comment: currentLocale.getCountry() returns AU